# How to set a bias on multiple methods within a class?

Tags: python, class, math, methods, syntax

Disclaimer: Python newb

My code

````
class summation():

    def __init__(self, num_1, num_2):

        self.add_1 = num_1 + num_2
        self.multiply = num_1 * num_2
        self.divide = num_1 / num_2
        self.difference = num_1 - num_2 

    def summate(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.add_1)

    def mult(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.multiply)

    def divis(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.divide)

    def diff(self):
        return '{}'.format(self.difference)

input_values = summation(int(input()), int(input()))

print('Sum =', input_values.add_1)
print('Multiplied =', input_values.multiply)
print('Divided =', input_values.divide)
print('The difference between the two values is ',input_values.difference)```
````

I want to include a bias method which will take the values input by the user and apply a bias on them that can be easily changed

I.E. user inputs (2) and (3) and the bias applies a 1.02 multiplier on them

so something that starts like this

```
bias = 1.04

def apply_bias(self):
        return input_values * bias
```

Obviously this doesn't work but it gives you an idea

Anyone have any ideas?
Cheers

Comment: When and how often do you want the bias applied? Should it only be applied to the initial 2 values that were passed to `__init__`, or to each of the four computed values?

Comment: It *sounds* like the bias should just be passed as a third argument to `__init__` (with a possible default value of 1) and applied to `num_1` and `num_2` before using them for anything else.

Comment: I want the bias to be applied every time I run the program. If I don't want it to run then I'll just set the bias to 1. I can't set it to zero because i'll imagine it'll bring back a NaN value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what your intending to do but I think one of these should work for you.

```
bias = 1.04

# Accept two values multiply them and the bias and return one result
def apply_bias(self, first, second):
    return (first * second) * bias

# or if you want to accept two values and return a tuple of two results
def apply_bias(self, first, second):
    return first * bias, second * bias
```

Edit after reading your comment I think I understand better.  Try this:

```
class Summation:
    def __init__(self, first, second, bias=1.04):
        self.first = first
        self.second = second
        self.bias = bias

    def summate(self, include_bias=False):
        result = self.first + self.second
        if not include_bias:
            return result
        return result * self.bias

    def mult(self, include_bias=False):
        result = self.first * self.second
        if not include_bias:
            return result
        return result * self.bias

    def divis(self, include_bias=False):
        result = self.first / self.second
        if not include_bias:
            return result
        return result * self.bias

    def diff(self, include_bias=False):
        result = self.first - self.second
        if not include_bias:
            return result
        return result * self.bias

    def apply_bias(self, bias):
        self.bias = bias

    def summary(self, include_bias=False):
        print(f'Sum = {input_values.summate(include_bias)}')
        print(f'Multiplied = {input_values.mult(include_bias)}')
        print(f'Divided = {input_values.divis(include_bias)}')
        print(f'The difference between the two values is {input_values.diff(include_bias)}')


input_values = Summation(int(input("first:")), int(input("second:")))
input_values.summary()
str_bias = input("bias:")
if str_bias:
    input_values.apply_bias(float(str_bias))
    input_values.summary(True)
```

This would print what your describing

```
first:2
second:2
Sum = 4
Multiplied = 4
Divided = 1.0
The difference between the two values is  0
bias:1.04
Sum = 4.16
Multiplied = 4.16
Divided = 1.04
The difference between the two values is  0.0
```

Comment: So more specifically

I want take two numbers from the user input and then add/divide/multiply and find the difference of the new numbers.

I then want to be able to set a multiplier(bias) to those printed values i.e.

if input values = 2, 2 then addition will make 4 and the bias will then make 4.16 if the multiplier is 1.04. 

I want to be able to do this every time the function is ran.

Comment: I think I understand, you want to apply the bias to all the methods... check the updated answer

Comment: Thanks JBird, I ended up implementing something similar after some time to think about it. Thanks for the confirmation.